# PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor for JMS DAO

Tags: spring, exception, jms, data-access-layer, spring-jms

I came across Spring's `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` and this seems perfect since this abstracts the exceptions being thrown in a DAO annotated with `@Repository`.

Now I have an application which uses JMS (ActiveMQ) instead of a database as a back-end. I'd like to use something like `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` to translate `JMSException`s to Spring's `DataAccessException`.

Before I go and re-invent the wheel I searched the web for such a thing but didn't find it. Maybe I'm using the wrong search keys, so as a second try, does anyone know of something like this existing, or do I have to invent this wheel?

---

**Update:**

It seems I have to create a `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` myself. I have done the following:

Implemented `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` on my abstract JMS DAO:

```
public abstract class AbstractJmsDao implements PersistenceExceptionTranslator
{
    public void throwException()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new JMSException("test");
        }
        catch (JMSException ex)
        {
            throw JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DataAccessException translateExceptionIfPossible(RuntimeException ex)
    {
        // translate exceptions here.
    }
}
```

Added `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` to my XML config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Annotated my DAO implementation with `@Repository`:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerJmsDao extends AbstractJmsDao implements CustomerDao
{
    public void test()
    {
        throwException();
    }
}
```

However when a `RuntimeException` is thrown, the `translateExceptionIfPossible()` never gets hit (checked with breakpoint). I'm obviously missing something here, however I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't translate to exceptions in the DataAccessException hierarchy, `JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException()` converts to Spring equivalents...

```
/**
 * Convert the specified checked {@link javax.jms.JMSException JMSException} to a
 * Spring runtime {@link org.springframework.jms.JmsException JmsException} equivalent.
 * @param ex the original checked JMSException to convert
 * @return the Spring runtime JmsException wrapping the given exception
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already knew of the `JmsUtils` class but this is an essential piece of the puzzle. I've updated my answer to where I am stuck now.

Comment: I am not sure that JMS really fits the DAO model, but to make this work, the PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor needs a PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor which needs a PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor which needs a reference to your custom PersistenceExceptionTranslator. Otherwise the ...PostProcessor does not know to apply your translator.